# One time change model attribute (column name) in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration

I created a model with an attribute "name" but I want to change it to "username".  Everything I've read about database migrations involves creating a class or some complicated stuff.  All I want to do is the equivalent of "UPDATE TABLE" in SQL.  How do you run a one-time database migration to change this?  I'm guessing it'd involve rails console and then some command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First:

```
rails g migration rename_name_column_to_username
```

Then in the generated rename_name_column_to_username.rb migration file:

```
class RenameNameColumnToUsername < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    rename_column :users, :name, :username
  end

  def self.down
    rename_column :users, :username, :name
  end
end
```

And then `rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't committed the code that originally created the "name" column, you can just go in to the old migration file that created that column and change `name` to `username` and then regenerate the schema.

But if you have committed the code, you should create a separate migration file that renames `name` to `username`.

This is important to keep track of the versioning of your database. So you should never really use manual SQL (ALTER TABLE ...) to change the schema.

Answer (score 0):

Run `rails g migration RenameNameToUsername`, which will create a new file in `db/migrate`.

Open that file, and add this into the `self.up` section:

```
rename_column :tablename, :name, :username
```

Then run `rake db:migrate`