# Rails model validation - validates_inclusion_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am having torubles with my model.
I have the code:

```
 class Typeofaid < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_inclusion_of :type, :in => %w(Food Water Health)
end
```

But whenever I type 'Food' etc in the box I get

```
`1 error prohibited this typeofaid from being saved:

    * Type is not included in the list
`
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to facturize your model using the type attribute instead of just entering some value using an input box.

"type" is a reserved column for single table inheritence in Rails.

Comment: So what exactly do I have to change?

Comment: Are Food, Water, Health child classes of "typeofaid" or just string values? If they are string values just change the attribute name from type to something different - maybe name.

Comment: They're strings. Okay how do I change the attribute name :/
Sorry this is my first RoR project

Comment: Rename the field name from `:type` to `:aid_type` and migrate the DB and see if it works.

Comment: No reason to be sorry. :) I also ran into this pitfall.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245115/one-time-change-model-attribute-column-name-in-ruby-on-rails

Found the answer there. Thanks flooooo (is that enough 'o's :P)

Answer (score 2):

Change it to the below code and try for it work fine for me in Rails3

```
validates :type, :inclusion => {:in => %w(Food Water Health)}
```